# Django checking for a query string

Tags: python, django, string, url, django-templates

When someone clicks on my site's logout link, I want them to be redirected to the login page but I want a message to pop up saying that they were successfully logged out. However, I don't want this behaviour to occur when someone normally visits the login page.

I decided to pass in a query string so now when someone hits logout they are redirected to `users/login/?logout`. How can I check for this in my template though? I want to do something like:

```
{% if ______ %}
*Message box appears*
{% endif %}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try `if logout in request.GET`, it it does not work try to add a value to the logout parameter (`?logout=1`) and then `if request.GET.logout` in the template. The `request` object should be available if the view uses a RequestContext (default if you are calling `render` or inheriting from a class based view)

Comment: The latter worked, thanks!

Comment: Django has this functionality built in. It's called "messenges"

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can simply use the built-in Django messaging feature!

Here's a simple example:

```
# views.py

from django.contrib import messages

def register(request):
  # Logic
  # ...

  messages.success(request, 'Registered successfully!')

  # ...
  # More logic
```

-

```
# example.html
{% if messages %}
  <ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
      <li class="{{ message.tags }}">
        {{ message|safe }}
          <a href="" class="close">X</a>
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endif %}
```

There's a more in-depth documentation available on Django's official docs website: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/messages/

Answer (score 0):

Referring to [this document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/), I believe what you are looking for is this

```
{% if not request.user.is_authenticated %}
    <p>You are logged out!</p>
{% endif %}
```